# Rails redirect_to with DELETE method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Simple question. Is it possible to use **redirect_to** in **Rails** specifying a *DELETE* method?. I want to be able to redirect to some *DELETE* path from a controller action. For example

```
def some_action
  # Do some stuff
  redirect_to edit_user_path(some_user_instance), method: :delete
end
```

Would appreciate the help. Thanks!!!.

**UPDATE**

I'm actually using *Devise* for authentication. And what I'm trying to do is to use *Devise*'s **edit_user_registration_path** route with the *DELETE* method from a controller.

Comment: is the initial request also delete? or is it a get/post ?

Comment: Try without the `edit` part: `redirect_to user_path(some_user_instance), method: :delete`

Comment: `redirect_to` no such options `:delete`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

CLOSED QUESTION!

There's no redirect_to available with DELETE method.

Regards.